# How to run Borland Database Engine in Docker?

Tags: windows, docker, bde

I have to maintain code which uses the Borland Database Engine (BDE). It runs on Windows 10. I want to create a docker image, where the BDE is installed.

**Approach A) "Silent Installation with BDE setup"**

The setup of the BDE seems to have no "silent" way for installation and pops up with some dialog during the setup proecess. This cannot be used in a `docker build` step, because there is no GUI.

=> It does not work.

Q: Is there a option at the setup to suppress the dialogs?

Q: Is the helper tool, which can approve the dialogs with "yes/ok" without user interaction?

**Approach B) "Manual installation by copy"**

Therefore I've tried to use a "manual installation" approach:

1. Install the BDE on my local machine
2. Copy all files of BDE from `c:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Borland Shared\BDE` into the docker image (with ADD in dockerfile)
3. Extract the registry keys for BDE from my local machine into a file `bde.reg`
4. Import the registry keys in the docker image from `bde.reg`

It **doesn't work** also.

Q: Do I forgot some registry keys, settings or files?

Comment: The BdeSetup.exe which I found is a WiSE package, you can silently install it with the `/S` flag. `BdeSetup.exe /S` however when it finishes prompts a little dialog for rebooting the system. I can't find anything to prevent this.

Comment: I used the /X switch and extract all files into a custom directory, then I copied the extracted dir to a virtual machine without bde, opened bdeadmin.exe, and it work.  With approach B which error do you have? [Here all switch of WiSE installer](https://www.itninja.com/blog/view/wise-setup-exe-switches)

Comment: @Max
I'm using Borland C++ Builder 5. Where did you found a BdeSetup.exe?

Comment: From googled I searched `bde setup`.